# Determine when/by whom a Sql Server 2000 service account was changed?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking into some backup issues on an old Sql 2000 server and I've narrowed it down to the fact that the Sql Agent account was changed.

The big question that I have is whether or not I can tell when this was changed and by whom it was changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows NT logs are the primary place to find when the account was first used - the eventlog comes with a find/filter option. However, it may have rolled depending on the configuration.

Check the SQL logs too - if the last restart was some time ago, it might give you a clue as to when.

If SQL Server is running under a domain account, it would be worth checking AD - many organisations put reference numbers against new accounts etc. Also have a trawl of any incident/request management system you might have.

Answer (score 1):

Event Logs can help (specifically the Security log) but only if audit policy for Account management has been set by the administrator.